# gradle how to manage jquery dependencies for java web app

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-mobile, gradle, dependencies

For web app, can Gradle download jquery and jquery mobile from a repository, and put into a jar with the following path?

```
    META-INF/resources/foo/bar/jquery-min.js
    META-INF/resources/foo/bar/jquery-mobile/jquery-mobile-min.js
    META-INF/resources/foo/bar/jquery-mobile/images/...
```

Use non-minified version for debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can.

For example make a configuration, declare the dependency for this configuration to the jquery lib. Then make a task of type `Jar` with something like

```
metaInf {
    from(zipTree(configurations.yourConfiguration.singleFile)) {
        include 'jquery-min.js'
        into 'resources/foo/bar/'
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is assuming your "dependency in the repository" is a JAR with the jquery files. If your jquery files are directly in the repository as artifacts, you have to write it a bit differently and don't need a `zipTree`.

Comment: tried to define a configuration jquery, got error message. updated the question. thanks.